# SwiftUI - Picker

Tags: enums, swiftui, picker

I am learning swift, now I have inserted 2 pickers that call the struct Animal.
What I can't understand is how to tell swift that if the first picker has selected an enum value, that same value must not be present in the enum available to the second picker, precisely because it has already been chosen.

Thanks so much :)

```
import SwiftUI

enum Animal: String, CaseIterable {
    
    case selectCase = "Select"
    case bear = "Bear"
    case cat = "Cat"
    case dog = "Dog"
    case lion = "Lion"
    case tiger = "Tiger"
    
    
    static var animals: [String] = [selectCase.rawValue, bear.rawValue, cat.rawValue, dog.rawValue, lion.rawValue, tiger.rawValue]
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var Picker1: String = Animal.animals[0]
    @State private var Picker2: String = Animal.animals[0]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Animals")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)) {
                        
                        Picker(selection: $Picker1, label: Text("Select first animal")) {
                            
                            ForEach(Animal.animals, id: \.self) { element in
                                Text(element)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Picker(selection: $Picker2, label: Text("Select second animal")) {
                            
                            ForEach(Animal.animals, id: \.self) { element2 in
                                Text(element2)
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                }.font(.system(size: 15))
            }.navigationBarTitle("List", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` to filter out the selected element from the first `Picker` unless the selected case is `selectCase`. Also made a few improvements for you.

1. Since the enum already conforms to `CaseIterable` protocol you don't have to create a custom `animals` array.
2. Also, you can use capitalized on rawValue instead of providing rawValue for each enum case which feels redundant.
3. Properties names should start with a lowercase letter and naming them `Picker1` cases confusion, naming the selected animal as `firstAnimal` or `selectedFirstAnimal` would be more convenient in the future.

Here's the code.

```
enum Animal: String, CaseIterable {
    case select
    case bear
    case cat
    case dog
    case lion
    case tiger
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var firstAnimal = Animal.allCases[0]
    @State private var secondAnimal = Animal.allCases[0]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Animals")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)) {
                        Picker(selection: $firstAnimal, label: Text("Select first animal")) {
                            ForEach(Animal.allCases, id: \.self) { element in
                                Text(element.rawValue.capitalized)
                            }
                        }
                        Picker(selection: $secondAnimal, label: Text("Select second animal")) {
                            ForEach(Animal.allCases.filter { $0 != firstAnimal || firstAnimal == .select }, id: \.self) { element2 in
                                Text(element2.rawValue.capitalized)
                            }
                        }
                }.font(.system(size: 15))
            }.navigationBarTitle("List", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.
I really thank you very much, you solved my problem.

:) Have a nice day

Thanks again